# Can anyone parse this rsync command into a list for use with asyncio.subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, rsync, python-asyncio

The `rsync` command:

```
sshpass -p 'test' rsync -v -e 'ssh -p 2200' --stats --timeout=60 anonymous@localhost:/DSK1/SSN/LOG[0-9]_F/17191/l134191l.17.bnx L134201707101100f.amalthea
```

This command works fine with `asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_shell` but I want to pass it to `create_subprocess_exec` as a list like

```
asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(*cmdList, stdin=..., ...)
```

I have tried simply splitting it with `cmdString.split()` to get

```
['sshpass', '-p', "'test'", 'rsync', '-v', '-e', "'ssh", '-p', "2200'", '--stats', '--timeout=60', 'anonymous@localhost:/DSK1/SSN/LOG[0-9]_F/17191/l134191l.17.bnx', 'L134201707101100f.amalthea']
```

but `rsync` is tripping up on quotes. Specifically:

```
Unexpected remote arg: anonymous@localhost:/DSK1/SSN/LOG[0-9]_F/17191/l134191i.17.bnx
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1361) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Comment: `asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_shell` invokes a sub-shell, that's why you can pass a whole string. `asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec` doesn't invoke a sub-shell. You don't need the quotes when all your commands and parameters are separated into list. You should end up with `["sshpass", "-p", "test", "rsync", "-v", "-e", "ssh -p 2200", "--stats", "--timeout=60", "anonymous@localhost:/DSK1/SSN/LOG[0-9]_F/17191/l134191l.17.bnx L134201707101100f.amalthea"]`.

Comment: This works. If you would format your comment as an answer (preferably including a brief explanation as to why you don't need quotes when a command is not executed in the shell) I will happily accept it. Given how many questions there are about parsing rsync commands into subprocess lists, I think it could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shells use whitespace as input field separators. To protect any whitespace, a quote is used, or the whitespace is escaped.

When running `asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec`, fields are already separated and whitespaces are **not** treated as input field separators.

`ssh -p 2200` should be placed in one field. `rsync` will see it as is. In shells it is quoted to protect the whitespace.

```
["sshpass", "-p", "test", "rsync", "-v", "-e", "ssh -p 2200", "--stats",
"--timeout=60", "anonymous@localhost:/DSK1/SSN/LOG[0-9]_F/17191/l134191l.17.‌​bnx",
"L134201707101100f.amalthea"]
```